# AutoHotkey Script to add attachment to current email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, autohotkey

I want to type a hotstring e.g. ,addfile in the body/subject of an email and a specific file will be added to the email that I'm writing.

I've got my main autohotkey script that I've setup with a hotstring to launch a script:

```
;AddFile
:*:,addfile::
Run "C:\LocationOfScript\AddAttachment.ahk"
```

This script (C:\LocationOfScript\AddAttachment.ahk) currently contains the following:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


#SingleInstance, Force

OL := ComObjActive("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
OL.Subject := "This is a test"
OL.Display
OL.Attachments.Add("C:\LocationOfAttachment.pdf")
```

I know this is not working because I'm creating a new email instead of adding an attachment to the email draft screen I'm typing the hotstring in.

How do I apply the code below to the email I'm writing?

```
OL.Attachments.Add("C:\LocationOfAttachment.pdf")
```

Comment: Can you use the `Application.ActiveWindow` method to get the currently active window and then add the attachment to that?

Comment: Would you have an example of how this command would be used?

Comment: Bearing in mind that I don't have AHK or Outlook on the same computer, both `CreateItem` and `ActiveWindow` are methods within the `Application` object. Therefore, changing your line to `OL := ComObjActive("Outlook.Application").ActiveWindow` might work. If it does then bear in mind that OL may be null (as in, there was no active window) or return a window where you cannot set the subject or add an attachment - so you'll need to gracefully handle all of those errors.

Comment: Have you tried the method suggested by Richard , and does your issue has any update?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar autokey script, which sounds like it could work, for your reference, you could try to check it: [Adding attachments to Outlook...](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=65541)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this post you've linked is the code I used however I can only get that to work on creating a new email and attaching a file. I can't set it up that it adds an attachment to an already opened new email.